# PHP validation: 4 x 3 optional drop-downs

Tags: php, validation

So, I have to code an error checking solution for the following situation:

- User has four chances to select from three drop-down menus:

  - Drop-down 1: Up to 15 options plus a blank (zero)
  - Drop-down 2: Up to 8 options plus a blank (zero)
  - Drop-down 3: Always 3 options plus a blank (zero)
- All four are optional, but if one of the three are selected, the other two cannot be left blank
- The values of the drop-down options are all numbers, with (blank) being zero
- Drop-down 1 and Drop-down 2 cannot be used again in any of the other three groups (i.e. if the users chooses to enter all four groups, there must be 8 unique values), but the third option can be repeated in the other groups

---

What is the most efficient way to

- (a) Check that if DD1 of G1 > 0, then DD2 and DD3 of G1 also > 0
- (b) Check that if DD1 of G1 = 0, then DD2 and DD3 of G1 also = 0
- (c) All combinations of drop-downs and groups of the above
- (d) Check I have up to 8 unique numbers, but ignoring zeroes, for the right amount of selected groups (i.e. either 2, 4, 6 or 8 - if only two groups are completed then there will be four zeroes, which is allowed).

---

I am aware of elseif, but the only way I can think to do point (a) and (b) above is something like:

```
if($dd1g1>0 && ($dd2g1>0 && $dd3g1>0))
{
 echo "DD1 of G1 is not blank, and DD2 and DD3 are also not blank.";
 // allowed
}
else
{
 echo "DD1 of G1 is not blank, but DD2 and DD3 are blank";
 // fail
}
```

I would have to repeat this 3^4 (=81) times just to satisfy two rules. Is there no easier way to do this?

Comment: Acquaint yourself with PHP control structures at http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php.

Comment: I am aware of elseif but it seems very inefficient. See edited question.

Comment: Define "efficient" -- these aren't particular memory or logic intense.  So why not treat as array of up to 4 elements, iterate that array and check the drop-down conditions hold, then check the array-wide conditions hold?  (Ie, your example has `$dd1g1`, which is hard to use: consider `$groups[0]['dd1']` is first group, dd1, etc.)

Comment: Are you worried about "efficiency" in terms of how long it will take to process this? Your server's CPU will knock this out in thousandths of a second. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @bishop has you on the right track.  Put the data into arrays.  You should be able to iterate the multi-dimensional array and use basic math to knock out most of the validation very easily.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with (edited for brevity and security - and yes I do have injection security in place in the real code):

```
if($dd1g1==0 && $dd2g1==0 && $dd3g1==0)
{
 // Group 1 are all zero, so clear
 $sql = "UPDATE blah SET dd1g1='0', dd2g1='0', dd3g1='0' WHERE id='".$blah."'";
}
else
{
 // Something is not zero in Group 1, so check they are all NOT zero
 if($dd1g1>0 && $dd2g1>0 && $dd3g1>0)
 {
  // Group 1 are all complete, so check there are no dupes
  if($dd1g1==$dd1g2 || $dd1g1==$dd1g3 || $dd1g1==$dd1g4 || $dd2g1==$dd2g2 || $dd2g1==$dd2g3 || $dd2g1==$dd2g3)
  {
   // There is a duplicate
   echo "Duplicates detected";
   die();
  }
  else
  {
   // No duplicates, so update
   $sql = "UPDATE blah SET dd1g1='".$dd1g1."', dd2g1='".$dd2g1."', dd3g1='".$dd3g1."' WHERE id='".$blah."'";
  }
 }
 else
 {
  // Group 1 is incomplete
  echo "Incomplete selection";
  die();
 }
}
```

[Then repeated for Groups 2, 3 and 4]

Any holes that anyone can spot?

Comment: Questions regarding "holes in my logic" belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/